# Are poetry.lock files OS independent?

Tags: python, package

I am creating a poetry.lock file on my Mac. Then, I am using it to build a Docker image based on Debian. My question is the following: is there any guarantee that the exact packages will be found by the Debian image?
I might be mistaken but I remember packages might not exist in every version for every OS. That’s seem reasonable when thinking about os specific packages (windows vs Unix). But how about Debian and Mac (both Unix based)? Should I expect at the least the majority of the packages to exist in the same version?

Comment: What does a `.lock` file have to do with the packages?  You can always do post-image loading and customization in your docker images, but what does this have to do with `.lock` and git?  It sounds like you have completely separate disparate questions going on here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Broadly, they are portable to any OS, yes.

But you must understand this has "nothing" to do with poetry nor pipenv nor pip but with the fact that **each package version can be distributed for multiple platforms**.

It is pip who will pick a particular wheel that matches the **compatible platform tags** for the system issuing the install (see the output of `pip debug`).

- For most pure python packages: only a wheel and a source distribution (tarball) can be found in the indexes, and pip will elect the wheel unless you tell it otherwise. So, the install will be pretty much the same across different OS. Only the python interpreter will be different.
- For packages featuring C (or whatever) extensions: the package will have been precompiled for a series of platforms and pip will pick the best mach for your system and python version. If no prebuilt wheel is compatible with your system, pip is forced to fallback to the source distribution and compile it, at which point you will be required whatever building toolchain that package needs (a C compiler, CPython headers and whatnot).

### The main purpose of a lockfile is a reproductible install

This is achieved through

- **Version pinning:** if no platform tag was compatible and the source distribution failed to build, pip would try to pick the next greatest version compatible with the requirement version range. In presence of a lockfile, that range is exactly one only version. Thus the installation would fail with no chances of picking another version.
- **Artifact hashing:** the downloaded artifacts are hashed and checked against the saved hashes in the lockfile. This simply prevents a rogue package index from tampering the source code nor the metadata of formerly published wheels or tarballs.

### Code from binary extensions will be equivalent yet inherently different across platforms

It is reasonable to trust the **binary extensions will be equivalent** and will come from the very same source code, executing the same behaviour with only potential platform-specific bugs. Yet, strictly speaking the compiled code will be usually different.

If you end up compiling the packages:

- for different platforms, the compilation will definetely be different
- for a given platform but different hardware, the compilation will most usually still be different
- for similar systems, the compilation toolchain can be different or be configured to perform different optimizations
- for the same system, the compilation might not be reproductible

If you end up downloading a prebuilt wheel:

- you only trust the package maintainers to have built all public wheels for different platforms out of the same source code version
- prebuilt binary extensions will be different for each platform tag set, and might present different bugs or issues

**This is rarely the case for pure Python packages:** theoretically possible, but maintainers will rather build a single wheel with compatibility boilerplate than craft different code bases for each Python version, even for Python-2&3 with two actual `py{2,3}-none-any` public wheels.

### Example

```
watchdog = [
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl", hash = "sha256:9693f35162dc6208d10b10ddf0458cc09ad70c30ba689d9206e02cd836ce28a3"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:aba5c812f8ee8a3ff3be51887ca2d55fb8e268439ed44110d3846e4229eb0e8b"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp310-cp310-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl", hash = "sha256:4ae38bf8ba6f39d5b83f78661273216e7db5b00f08be7592062cb1fc8b8ba542"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:ad6f1796e37db2223d2a3f302f586f74c72c630b48a9872c1e7ae8e92e0ab669"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:922a69fa533cb0c793b483becaaa0845f655151e7256ec73630a1b2e9ebcb660"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl", hash = "sha256:b2fcf9402fde2672545b139694284dc3b665fd1be660d73eca6805197ef776a3"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:3386b367e950a11b0568062b70cc026c6f645428a698d33d39e013aaeda4cc04"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl", hash = "sha256:8f1c00aa35f504197561060ca4c21d3cc079ba29cf6dd2fe61024c70160c990b"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl", hash = "sha256:b52b88021b9541a60531142b0a451baca08d28b74a723d0c99b13c8c8d48d604"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:8047da932432aa32c515ec1447ea79ce578d0559362ca3605f8e9568f844e3c6"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl", hash = "sha256:e92c2d33858c8f560671b448205a268096e17870dcf60a9bb3ac7bfbafb7f5f9"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-pp37-pypy37_pp73-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:b7d336912853d7b77f9b2c24eeed6a5065d0a0cc0d3b6a5a45ad6d1d05fb8cd8"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_aarch64.whl", hash = "sha256:cca7741c0fcc765568350cb139e92b7f9f3c9a08c4f32591d18ab0a6ac9e71b6"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_armv7l.whl", hash = "sha256:25fb5240b195d17de949588628fdf93032ebf163524ef08933db0ea1f99bd685"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_i686.whl", hash = "sha256:be9be735f827820a06340dff2ddea1fb7234561fa5e6300a62fe7f54d40546a0"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_ppc64.whl", hash = "sha256:d0d19fb2441947b58fbf91336638c2b9f4cc98e05e1045404d7a4cb7cddc7a65"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_ppc64le.whl", hash = "sha256:3becdb380d8916c873ad512f1701f8a92ce79ec6978ffde92919fd18d41da7fb"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_s390x.whl", hash = "sha256:ae67501c95606072aafa865b6ed47343ac6484472a2f95490ba151f6347acfc2"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl", hash = "sha256:e0f30db709c939cabf64a6dc5babb276e6d823fd84464ab916f9b9ba5623ca15"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-win32.whl", hash = "sha256:e02794ac791662a5eafc6ffeaf9bcc149035a0e48eb0a9d40a8feb4622605a3d"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-win_amd64.whl", hash = "sha256:bd9ba4f332cf57b2c1f698be0728c020399ef3040577cde2939f2e045b39c1e5"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-win_ia64.whl", hash = "sha256:a0f1c7edf116a12f7245be06120b1852275f9506a7d90227648b250755a03923"},
    {file = "watchdog-2.1.6.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:a36e75df6c767cbf46f61a91c70b3ba71811dfa0aca4a324d9407a06a8b7a2e7"},
]
weasyprint = [
    {file = "weasyprint-54.1-py3-none-any.whl", hash = "sha256:27c078ded67a43c9a05c349eda01ea327805d48e5c3ca3b704f57eb82bd78592"},
    {file = "weasyprint-54.1.tar.gz", hash = "sha256:fa57db862e06bd01c5e7d82dad399b3b9952a39827023c17bee9b1c061ff1bbd"},
]
```

In this fragment of a poetry.lock file you can see the hashes for watchdog==2.1.6 and weasyprint==54.1. For weasyprint, the wheel tagged `py3-none-any` will probably be the wheel to be actually downloadad in any system.

Yet, for watchdog, the elegible wheel will depend both on your OS and your hardware, aside from your python version!

- Any x86_64 linux box will pick `watchdog-2.1.6-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`
- An arm64 MacOS box with CPython-3.8 will pick `watchdog-2.1.6-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl`
- An arm64 MacOS box with PyPy-3.7 will be forced to build `watchdog-2.1.6.tar.gz`, which could lead to the whole installation failing if it can't achieve that.
- A future MacOS with CPython-3.11 ill also need to build `watchdog-2.1.6.tar.gz`

You can also check those hashes in PyPI's website https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/2.1.6/#files

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So is there a chance that a different package version will be installed if one for the current OS can't be found, or will it throws an error? But if I get your point, different OS could have different source code for C packages even for the same version. Is this common also for pure Python packages?

Comment: There is NO chance a different version will be installed other than the locked. In the worst scenario, no wheel is compatible for you so you will be forced to build the source distribution. Even if the binary extensions will be inherently different, they should be equivalent and will most usually come from the same exact source code. This is rarely the case for pure Python packages: theoretically possible, but maintainers will rather build a single wheel with compatibility boilerplate than craft different code bases for each Python version, even for Python-2&3 with 2 `py{2,3}-none-any` wheels.

Comment: Could add some structure to the answer? Maybe an example of cross-platform cases depending whether the package is pure python vs C. After reading it, I am more confused that before. E.g. what is the reason to have both hash and version number?

Comment: Fair enough, the answer grew stochastocally. Not really sure on how to sort it out, though.